# how to write .iim file for imacros

Tags: imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=URL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=6
```

This is the code I'm using for `.iim` file to click on a button on a website. But I couldn't understand what this code is and what are those `tag pos` and `button attr`. When I run this code there's an error like this.

```
RuntimeError: element INPUT specified by * was not found, line: 3
```

What is this error and how to tackle it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
```

This is a button that submits something. Find that button on web page. Right click on it and select "Inspect Element". Then you will see HTML code of that button.

If it has property name="somename" or id="someid" then you will put

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=NAME:somename

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=ID:someid
```

Comment: `<span class="btn btn-success btn-slot remote-ajax ajax-init reset reset-btn" data-load="game">Spin</span>`                                        This is the html code for that button. How to get Id or name now?

Comment: TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"btn btn-success btn-slot remote-ajax ajax-init reset reset-btn"